# Excel Data Validation Numbers,letters,numbers (CAPS letter)

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

So i found a Code that works for number then Letter, I tried to modify is so the user entering data in the cell need to be `ex:"52TSQ1234512345"`. I got it to the point where they have to enter `ex: "12PQS"` (numbers and letters are examples, it can be any number and and letter(in CAPS). This is what i got so far but something is off, and i can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

`"=AND(LEN(A1)=15,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))),CODE(MID(LOWER(A1),3))>=97,CODE(MID(LOWER(A1),3))<=122)),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,10)))"`

Comment: okay, so =AND(LEN(A1)=15,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))),CODE(MID(LOWER(A1),3,3))>=97,CODE(MID(LOWER(A1),3,3))<=122,ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,10)))

works but i need to apply it to cells C3:C600 when i switch out "A1" with those cell names it gives me and error/ i cant put any number in the cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`=AND(LEN(A1)=15,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))),CODE(MID(LOWER(A1),3,3))>=97,CODE(MID(LOWER(A1),3,3))<=122,ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,10)))`

Two issues

- Your `Mid` formula had a missing argument
- invalid `()` positions, in particular the two at the end of `CODE(MID(LOWER(A1),3))<=122))`

Comment: Thank you so much it works finally! i knew i wasn't to far off. I'd up vote you if i could but i guess i don't have enough rep.

Comment: Will, do. One question though. I'm now trying to have this be a rule for C3:C600 and now it doesn's seem to work. I just replace "A1" in this formula to "C3:C600" right?

Comment: Nevermind. I found out the Problem some cells in that row contain "UNKNOWN" so i gotta make an exception for that.